# Is there a word for the action of lifting the mouse to go further?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

Using a computer mouse to point to a far away target and running out of table surface (or hand range), one typically lifts the mouse, moves it in the opposite direction, puts it back down, and continues the movement.

Is there an English word or expression for this action? If not, how would you concisely refer to it in a text? (I thought of *rowing* or *scraping* with the mouse.)

Comment: Ugh. Whatever it is, it drives me nuts. I can't stand when people have their mouse sensitivity so low that you have to do this 10 times to get the cursor across the screen.

Comment: In Middle English they called it _moosing_.

Comment: I used to hate running out of real estate with the mouse.  Thank God I now have a scroll wheel on my mouse!

Comment: They had computer mice in Middle English?

Comment: @xdumaine I hope I'm not reaching across generational chasms when I say this, but in computer games where you are "steering" or "turning" in one direction continuously, you could easily run out of desktop real estate.

Comment: @congusbongus Oh, definitely in games, but you should still, in my opinion, be able to move the cursor from one side of your monitor to the other without picking up the mouse. Continuously turning, or turning very quickly is why some PC gamers use [trackball mice](https://www.google.com/search?q=gamer+trackball+mouse&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=6rxKUvmOM4T29gT65YCICQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1858&bih=995&dpr=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Lifting the mouse*** is perfectly adequate, and is used in the business to describe this exact action. For example, take this excerpt from [a magazine review of a mouse](http://www.pcauthority.com.au/Review/286656,corsairs-vengeance-m60-gaming-mouse-a-very-good-work-in-progress.aspx):

> The ability to tweak **lift-off distance** is great; we like to **lift our mouse** a lot, so by setting the M60 to not track at any height, we ended up with solid mousing.

There's also a page by a mouse manufacturer about the related jargon [**lift-off distance**](http://www.razerzone.com/mouseguide/technology/15).

It is specific enough because it's about the only reason to lift the mouse.

Comment: Maybe gamers don't always use their mouses/mice flat on a surface, but play using the mouse more like a joystick, up in the air kind of thing.

Answer (score 5):

I always think of this as a kind of circular movement, so I too rather like your ‘rowing’ coinage.

However, I think that to me (being somewhat unaccustomed to the seafaring ways), a more familiar and easily recognisable turn of phrase would be something like ***pedalling*** or ***cycling***, both of which are based on similar circular movements used to propel something forward.

Comment: If "rowing" works, the O.P. might want to consider "oaring," too. The verb "oar" can mean _to traverse with or as if with oars_. Also, I like your suggestion of "cycling" because, generically, "cycling" can refer to any cyclical motion, making it especially appropriate.

Comment: I always thought of it as *relocating* the mouse.

Comment: But it's sort of a backwards circular motion, making it more like *backpedalling* -- but that gives the wrong idea altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply not say that you are ***reorienting*** your cursor? Or ***realigning*** it?

Comment: I think it should be reorienting the mouse instead of the cursor, as it is the physical object that we are changing the position of, instead of the icon on the screen

Answer (score 1):

How about "jumping" or "skipping"?

(I don't really like the latter, but added it so that my answer would be >30 characters)

Comment: From a theoretical viewpoint, this is quite good—but I think it would be quite likely to be mixed up with the opposite phenomenon of the mouse suddenly _jumping_ to some unrelated location on the screen without any user interaction.

Comment: This suggestion seems a lot more murine than the seafaring analogies with oars. Maybe 'hopping' or 'popping' would work, too.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the term "palming" your mouse. But this does not seem to be popular doing a google search.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard word or phrase for this action, but your suggestion of *rowing* is nice, because it's analogous to the upstroke in which the movement of the oar doesn't affect the movement of the boat (where the oar is the mouse and the boat is the cursor).

You might be able to use "recoil" as the mouse moves forward to move the cursor, then the user *recoils* the mouse to continue moving the cursor. *Recoil* indicates a jerky backward sort of motion in response to an opposite motion or action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any standard term, either, but the first word that came to my mind was *backtracking*. American Heritage defines the verb as:

> **backtrack** (*v*.) To go back over the course by which one has come.

which seems like an okay match.

I could see using *backtracking* in a sentence such as:

> *My mouse setttings are too slow; whenever I want to get my cursor to the top of the screen, I keep having to backtrack over the mousepad two or three times!*

Comment: I think I would understand ‘backtracking’ in this context to mean that you had moved the cursor _too far_ and were therefore retracing your hand’s movements to get back to where you were supposed to be.

Comment: @Janus - That's a fair criticism, and I wasn't entirely thrilled with my suggestion, either. I suppose it hinges on how the word would be used in context. I've decided to elaborate in my answer, thanks to your helpful comment.

Comment: In your example, it works—but I would find it even more natural if the first part had “too fast” rather than “too slow” (and of course without the “two or three times” at the end).

Comment: @Janus - I suppose it depends on what's backtracking: the cursor, or the hand.

Answer (score -1):

How about "lifting forwards — forward in the USA"?

Comment: I do not understand your suggestion at all. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I think the " — forward in the USA" wasn't meant to be part of the quote.